# Detecting named view is used

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am looking to build a layout with a dynamic side-bar. The sidebar on its own has its own template, but I do not want that to be rendered unless the underlying router-view is used. Below the pseudo-code:

```
<template>
  <transition name="slide">
    <div class="sidebar" v-if="showSidebar">
      <SidebarHeader />
      <router-view name="side"><router-view>
      <SidebarFooter>
    </div>
  </transition>
  <div class=main><router-view></router-view></div>
</template>
```

Is there any obvious way of achieving that? I failed to find any property or function on `$router` or `$route` object.

As a workaround I've made `Sidebar` component that has to be used for each sidebar view, but is there a better option?

Comment: Use the `meta` property of the `route` and attach anything you want, like ` meta: { sidebar : false }`, then use `this.$route.meta.sidebar !== false` to display the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the answer - it requires a bit of trick int he routes:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: 'Layout',
  children: [
    { 
      path: '',
      components: { default: SomeMainComponent },
      children: [
        { path: '' },
        { 
          path: '',
          components: { side: SideBox },
          children: [
            path: 'hello',
            component: HelloSidebox
          ]
        } 
      ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

That empty route `{path: ''}` is to prevent the next route from being displayed for the exact route match and only render SideBox component for any matching sub-routes.